# CSS Drawing a line between two elements

Tags: javascript, css, line

I've been trying to draw a line down the middle of a series of circles however if I set a line (`.Line1`) to fit between the first and last element then it's drawn from the top left of the first element and not centralised. If i set a line (`.Line2`) to fit in the middle by changing the percentages it will look fine at 100% zoom however if you zoom in or out of the screen it moves around.

I know it is possible to do using pure javascript however I cannot figure out how to do it with css created elements.

```
<style>
.A,.B,.C,.D, .E {
position: absolute;
width: 45px;
height: 45px;
-webkit-border-radius: 50%;
-moz-border-radius: 50%;
border-radius: 50%;
border: 2px solid black;
background: lightblue;
}
.A {
top: 10%;
left: 50%;
}
.B {
top: 25%;
left: 50%;
}
.C {
top: 40%;
left: 50%;
}
.D {
top: 55%;
left: 50%;
}
.E {
top: 70%;
left: 50%;
}
.Line1{
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 10%;
height: 60%;
width: 4px;
background: black;
}
.Line2{
position: absolute;
left: 51.3%;
top: 15%;
height: 60%;
width: 4px;
background: black;
}
</style>

<body>
<div class = "A"></div>
<div class = "B"></div>
<div class = "C"></div>
<div class = "D"></div>
<div class = "E"></div>
<div class = "Line1"></div>
<div class = "Line2"></div>
</body>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZWMbNe

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take border, width and height into account. you cannot draw half a pixel. For example this is a center line:

```
.A,.B,.C,.D, .E {
  position: absolute;
  width: 46px;
  height: 46px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background: lightblue;
}

.Line1{
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 10%;
  height: 60%;
  width: 2px;
  background: black;
  transform: translate(24px,23px);
}
```

Comment: This solution will work. But this is a good CSS hack overcompansating for a weak HTML structure. OP needs to structure your HTML better.

Answer (score 0):

give one of the lines a margin-left that will be equal to half of the circle's width.
that way the line will always stay in the middle no matter if you zoom in or out.

```
.Line1{
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 15%;
height: 60%;
width: 4px;
margin-left:23px;  
margin-top:0px;  
background: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your circles into a parent Element. So that you can align the Black line according to the parent `Div` and not the window size.

Moreover you can use the pseudo selector `:before` or `:after` for the line.

**HTML**

```
<div class="cirCont">
  <div class="A"></div>
  <div class="B"></div>
  <div class="C"></div>
  <div class="D"></div>
  <div class="E"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.A,.B,.C,.D, .E {
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background: lightblue;
}

.cirCont{
  float:left;
  position:relative;
  top: 100px;
  left: 50%;
}

.cirCont:after{
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 2px);
  top: 10%;
  height: 80%;
  width: 4px;
  background: black;
  z-index:10;
}
```

Checkout this [pen](http://codepen.io/rmrinmoy/pen/eZLJzG)